# Inputs field hidden when android virtual keyboard open in phonegap

Tags: android, sdk

I am creating an application with phonegap and jquery mobile which has many input forms in it. When an input field is focused the virtual keyboard comes up and hides the form fields and cant see what I am typing in android.

Answer (score 0):

in manifest

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale
```

This allow Android to default behavior to shrink the view on display of keyboard